# Extract url from html with imacros

Tags: firefox, imacros

I'm trying to get the url inside the href of this html:

```
<a class="more-info" rel="nofollow" href="http://perfil.mercadolivre.com.br/SPEEDSHOPSHOW" target="_blank" title="Ver mais dados deste vendedor">Ver mais dados deste vendedor</a>
```

from this url:

```
http://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-743261880-sony-carregador-portatil-10000mah-cp-v10-original-lacrado-_JM
```

with this iMacros code:

```
URL GOTO=http://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-743261880-sony-carregador-portatil-10000mah-cp-v10-original-lacrado-_JM
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=A:more-info EXTRACT=HREF
```

but I'm getting this:

```
#EANF#
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to indicate a proper attribute:

```
URL GOTO=http://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-743261880-sony-carregador-portatil-10000mah-cp-v10-original-lacrado-_JM
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:more-info EXTRACT=HREF
```